# Consent SDK : consentStatus become UNKNOWN again

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently trying to integrate the Google Consent SDK. 
something is happening that I don't understand with the `onConsentInfoUpdated(consentStatus:ConsentStatus)` function

1. User opens the app for the first time and makes a choice when the popup is diplayed
   `Consent.Status -> UNKNOWN`
2. User kills / re-opens the app.
   Sometimes `Consent.Status -> PERSONALIZED` or `Consent.Status -> UNKNOWN` and user makes a choice again.

   - here my code:

```java
    fun requestConsent(activity: Activity) {
        val consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(activity)
        val publisherIds = arrayOf(activity.getString(R.string.admob_publisher_id))
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, object : ConsentInfoUpdateListener {
            override fun onConsentInfoUpdated(consentStatus: ConsentStatus) {
                Log.d("test--", consentStatus.toString())
                when (consentStatus) {
                    ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED -> showPersonalizedAds()
                    ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED -> showNonPersonalizedAds()
                    ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN -> loadConsentForm(activity)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(errorDescription: String) {
                 //onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun showPersonalizedAds() {
        ConsentInformation.getInstance(activity).consentStatus = ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED
    }

    private fun showNonPersonalizedAds() {
        ConsentInformation.getInstance(activity).consentStatus = ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED
    }
```

- here my logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, all advertisers are selected in the admob console. That's why I was able to solve my problem by going to the blocking settings section for users in the European Union.

click *Blocking controls* and then *EU user consent*

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7666519#providers

Answer (score 1):

This is the first result that came up on Google and I tried your solution but it didn't resolve the issue. In my case I was using:

```
com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6
```

The issue was resolved by upgrading to:

```
com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8
```

Google removed the restriction on using Google rendered consent form with the commonly used set of ad technology providers in 1.0.6 and changed logic for re-consent prompts in 1.0.8 - as seen here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android/blob/master/ChangeLog.md

Could it be that you also changed your library version without realising?

Comment: I don't think so because it seems to me that 1.0.8 didn't exist at the time I asked the question.